# Optional properties based on generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to make a property optional based on the generic type. I've tried the following:

```js
interface Option<T extends 'text' | 'audio' | 'video'> {
    id: string;
    type: T;
    text: T extends 'text' ? string : undefined;
    media: T extends 'audio' | 'video' ? T : undefined;
}

const option: Option<'text'> = { text: "test", type: "text", id: "opt1" };
```

So the idea is that the property `text` only is defined for `Option<'text'>` and `media` only is defined for `Option<'audio' | 'video'>`.

However, the ts compiler gives me the following error:

```js
Property 'media' is missing in type '{ text: string; type: "text"; id: string; }' 
but required in type 'Option<"text">'.ts(2741)
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't have the optionality of a property depend on a generic type parameter in an interface. You can however use a type alias and intersections instead:

```
type Option<T extends 'text' | 'audio' | 'video'> = {
    id: string;
    type: T;
} 
& (T extends 'text' ? { text: string } : {})
& (T extends 'audio' | 'video' ? { media: T }: {});


const option: Option<'text'> = { text: "test", type: "text", id: "opt1" };
```

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7APAFShAHsCKAJgM5QDk+eZUAPuQIYCuhy1dZAbgoREmQHxQAvFADeAKChSo3AFxRiwAE4IUAcwDck6aEjyMWgL5RxAMigAKLLnxFSFG9QD8YqJWDzFK9VGPzRhgCUZpbWeAQkDMystORcPHxQLqJQALYQLPT6vv5BWuLiAMaoilBI8Mgo8nCIqGgOVIIiKe7yAET4im0ANG7gEO3uPTKE7eXAAIxtvhpAA)

Although you are probably better off with a  [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions):

```
type Option = 
| { id: string; type: 'text'; text: string }
| { id: string; type: 'audio' | 'video'; media: 'audio' | 'video' };


const option: Extract<Option, {type: 'text' }> = { text: "test", type: "text", id: "opt1" };

function withOption(o: Option) {
    switch(o.type) {
        case 'text': console.log(o.text); break;
        default: console.log(o.media); break;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7KBeKAoAPlA3lAgCYBcUAzsAE4IoDmA3FKJOQOTAQAew7zXXuSq0GUAL64CRMpRp0mLcBA4BDAK7Fk7KHnYA3EhCT8oAWwhbVazdt1QDRkxMZY3AY1RUoSeMhTkAKK81KruwAA8cIioADQErCoOgnwSAHwY0inkAERcVDnxibkphTK5vsAAjDkubgBm6ijh-lAA7gjAABbR-gAUSOS9qACUBFhQk5QdwO5dAwB0iWP4E1Pr7qoU0Jw8fOSeKBRIADYQCydI9IspI8wARtQQqgDWruvrxBD1GifAB15TudLtckAsLFY7lBHs83mtJpJxNgsEA)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a union:

```typescript
type Option<T extends 'text' | 'audio' | 'video'> =
    {
        id: string;
        type: T;
    }
    &
    (
        T extends 'text'
        ? {text: string}
        : {media: T}
    );

const option: Option<'text'> = { text: "test", type: "text", id: "opt1" };
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=75#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7APAFShAHsCKAJgM5QDk+eZUAPuQIYCuhy1dZAbgoREmQHxQAvACgo4qAG8xE2dwBcUYsABOCFAHMA3DNnjQkRRh2yAvrqgAyCwAoLsrLnxFSFJ2XsSA-FMrBFymqa5noSipIAthAs9EYhEgCUOiIAxqjKUEjwyCiKcIioaG5UgkJSUH6KAET4ylUANBXgENV+DVAKUFVZwACMVVCmWkA)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have a generic type using string values like what you are mentioned, `interface Option<T extends 'text' | 'audio' | 'video'>`.

But if you want to have something like use below:

- `option.ts`

```js
interface Option {
    id: string;
    type: 'text' | 'audio' | 'video' | undefined;
}
```

- `media-option.ts`

```js
interface MediaOption extends Option {
    media: string;
}
```

- `text-option.ts`

```js
interface TextOption extends Option {
    text: string;
}
```

so; When you want to use them, you have to cast to a specific type between if it's media or text option based in type.

```js
let option: Option = {id:'1',type: 'audio'}

if(option.type === 'audio'){
let media = option as MediaOption
}
```

Comment: *"It's not possible to have a generic type using string values like what you are mentioned"* It [*seems* possible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=75#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7APAFShAHsCKAJgM5QDk+eZUAPuQIYCuhy1dZAbgoREmQHxQAvACgo4qAG8xE2dwBcUYsABOCFAHMA3DNnjQkRRh2yAvrqgAyCwAoLsrLnxFSFJ2XsSA-FMrBFymqa5noSipIAthAs9EYhEgCUOiIAxqjKUEjwyCiKcIioaG5UgkJSUH6KAET4ylUANBXgENV+DVAKUFVZwACMVVCmWkA)... :-)

Comment: As you mention as I said, I gave you a proper answer based in your question

Comment: 1. It's not my question. 2. The statement I quoted is incorrect. Did you not understand that was my point? 3. This answer does not do what the OP asked for.

Comment: I see, It's my fault to mention you as who is questioning, but the different between your answer and mine is related to concepts itself, he use interface to defined whats needed, and based on that I gave him my answer, It's depends on his question maybe my answer is not what he need exactly, but its do the required job.